# How to get the value in Angular after CTRL + V detects

Tags: javascript, angular, copy-paste, keypress

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (keypress)="keyPress($event)">

@HostListener('window:keydown',['$event'])
keyPress($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) && $event.keyCode == 86){

        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
```

I am trying to detect when user CTRL V on the text field. Now I want to get the value.

When I tried to console.log() the value it is blank. How do I get the value after CTRL V?

Answer (score 0):

we can use onPaste event of input elements

In Template use paste event

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (paste)="onPaste($event)" 
(keypress)="keyPress($event)" />
```

In component, you can check for result after paste

```
onPaste(event): void {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(this.value));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the function change or onChange

```js
onChangeEx(event) {
  console.log(event.value);
}
```

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="onChangeEx($event)" (keypress)="keyPress($event)">
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: onChangeEx(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$event.preventDefault(); repalce : console.log
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).